# How to get child based on value inside it, without knowing the child. in flutter firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I want to get child from value inside it without knowing the child, but by searching for user.uid(lecturerId) inside it

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyF09.png)

edit1:
I would like to get -LckcCyfPfwCNXJRDfgR from "classData" without it knowing it, by finding 
"lecturerId" = VrvypxmFmiSWqzzH3K50ZgtaYtF3

Comment: can you elaborate your question a bit? What type of child you are trying to build which depends on the value.

Comment: I would like to get -LckcCyfPfwCNXJRDfgR from "classData" without it knowing it, by finding "lecturerId" = VrvypxmFmiSWqzzH3K50ZgtaYtF3